# Download xls file from application rails 4

Tags: excel, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4 application, where i have a xls file in my applications public folder ,and am having a link in view page after clicking that link that xls file should download to system.no need to write anything in that file its just a default template.

**I use:**

view:

```
<%= link_to "Dowload Template", admin_job_templates_path, :file_name => 'Job_Upload_Template.xlsx' %>
```

controller :

```
def index 
  require 'open-uri'
  file_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/Job_Upload_Template.xlsx"
  send_file file_path, :filename => "Job_Upload_Template.xlsx", :disposition => 'attachment'
end
```

also tried send_data method

```
def index 
      require 'open-uri'
      url = "#{Rails.root}/public/Job_Upload_Template.xlsx"
      data = open(url).read
      send_data data, :filename =>'Job Template'
end
```

Am getting the below error.

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -
>   /home/amp/workspace/LA_Tracker/public/Job_Upload_Template.xlsx

am not able to dowload the file, Plese help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that file doesn't exist. Do you have the capitalization correct? Double check. Also, what happens if you type:

```
ls /home/amp/workspace/LA_Tracker/public/Job_Upload_Template.xlsx
```

into the command line? Can your OS find the file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. its not listing the above file, mismatch with the file template format.